# Setting textbox innertext of an externally loaded webpage using AgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, html-agility-pack

I am trying to write a code which automatically fills in a textbox inside of an external webpage. So I write code below inside of a buttonclick event and what I want it to do is, just load the external webpage and fill the existing textbox with a text. However, I couldn't get this working. It doesn't set anything at all.

```
    String Url2dehands = "http://www.hereisthewebsite.be";
    HtmlWeb mvWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = mvWeb.Load(Url2dehands);
    HtmlNode mvTextBox = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@id='id_ofthe_textbox']");
    mvTextBox.InnerHtml= "assdsda";
```

Comment: I don't know much about HTML and nothing about that API, but I feel like the `InnerHtml` property would just change the value between the tags. Maybe try something that sets the `Text` attribute of the node?

Comment: The Html Agility Pack is for parsing the page, and getting information out of it, not for manipulating a browser or simulating user action. You should use the WebBrowser control instead.

Comment: Is there any webbrowser control in asp.net? I know in c# but I am not sure about asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need might be http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it. What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be automated as well.

Also, you can use [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/).
This will write code for you in a set of different languages. You can then use this code to automate the process.